Can you have a foreach loop above stages in a Python DVC pipeline?
I want to use the foreach-do construct to iterate over a series of experiments.
From the docs, I understand the standard approach is as follows:
dvc.yaml
stages:
  prepare_data:
    foreach: ${experiments}
    do:
      cmd: python stages/prepare_data.py "${item}"
      deps:
        - data/data_source.csv
        - stages/prepare_data.py
      params:
        - prepare_data
      outs:
        - input_data/${item}.csv
  fit_model:
    foreach: ${experiments}
    do:
    ... etc

But is it possible to instead loop over each experiment and execute the stages in sequence:
foreach: ${experiments}
do:
  stages:
    prepare_data:
      cmd: python stages/prepare_data.py "${item}"
      deps:
        - data/data_source.csv
        - stages/prepare_data.py
      params:
        - prepare_data
      outs:
        - input_data/${item}.csv
    fit_model:
      ... etc

This doesn't work but I just want to make sure I'm not missing something because it would be nice in my case.
'./dvc.yaml' validation failed: 2 errors.                             

extra keys not allowed, in foreach

extra keys not allowed, in do, line 3, column 3
   2 do:                                                                                                                                                           
   3   stages:                                                                                    

